# Is string interpolation bad practice for NSDate variables?

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

A `UICollectionViewCell` contains a `UILabel` with the text set as:

```
textLabel.text = String(format: "\(aDate)", arguments: [])
```

I observed that the `aDate` literal causes the collection view scrolling to lag significantly. `aDate` is not a lazy loading variable but a simple `var aDate: NSDate?`. Btw the reason that I don't just use `textLabel.text = "\(aDate)"` is that the string actually contains more literals.

Is it bad practise to interpolate a string with an `NSDate` variable?
Do I have to use a `NSDateFormatter`?

Comment: NSDateFormatter is also inherently not so performant. However, it does provide 2 things. 1. Able to reason what it does. 2. Customize what it can do.   You might be able to cache with NSDateFormatter in some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue of the scroll lagging was due to the `NSLayoutConstraints` of the label. The solution was to anchor the label to the `UICollectionViewCell` content view instead of other views inside the content view. Found that out with Allocations Instruments analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to present NSDate objects to the user you should use NSDateFormatter, this will ensure that dates will be presented correctly to the user based on their locale, set calendar, and general display preferences. This is considered the best practice. You should also do the same for any numerical presentation, names, distances, or other display strings that could be culturally different depending on where you are on the globe.

Comment: Thank Danny, the label is only visible for the developer. My question aims only at the performance when interpolating a string with NSDate.

Comment: Why not just use `date.description` then?